# Using Sapply function in R

Tags: r

I would like to find maximum value of 3 columns. Please see details below,

- Flights name column: AI, KF, AA
- Domestic price column: 14.5, 23.4, 14.6
- Internation price column: 14.5, 23.4, 14.6
- round trip column: 44.34, 35.78, 31.24.

In R:

```
air <- data.frame(DomPrice = c(14.5, 23.4, 14.6), 
                  IntPrice = c(14.5, 23.4, 14.6), 
                  RoundTrip = c(44.34, 35.78, 31.24), 
                  row.names = c("AI", "KF", "AA"))
```

I want to find the names of the flights which have the maximum price, domestic price, international price, round trip using sapply in R.

Table name/csv file name = Air

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you show the work you've done to try to accomplish this yourself and provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example we can help you a lot more. For more understanding, see why is ["please help" not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: Vincent, i have all values in column in excel. Its quite big so i cant put all values as vector and use rownames(air)[sapply(air, which.max)] do u have any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)
air %>% 
  rownames_to_column("flights") %>% 
  gather(k,v,-flights) %>% 
  group_by(k) %>%
  mutate(M=ifelse(max(v)==v,T,F)) %>% 
  filter(M) %>% 
  select(-M)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   k [3]
  flights k             v
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 KF      DomPrice   23.4
2 KF      IntPrice   23.4
3 AI      RoundTrip  44.3
```

In base R you can try

```
data.frame(flight= row.names(air)[apply(air, 2, which.max)], 
           value = apply(air, 2, max))
          flight value
DomPrice      KF 23.40
IntPrice      KF 23.40
RoundTrip     AI 44.34
```

If you have trouble with `NA`'s you have to add a `na.rm == TRUE` like `max(x, na.rm =TRUE)`

Comment: `filter(ifelse(max(v) == v, T, F))` will provide the same output, letting you skip the `mutate - select(-...)`

Comment: @Jimbou data.frame(flight= row.names(air)[apply(air, 2, which.max)], 
           value = apply(air, 2, max))
What is 2 referring to?

Comment: @Krishna check `?apply()` and read `MARGIN`. There you find:  vector giving the subscripts which the function will be applied over. `1` indicates rows, `2` indicates columns...